# Get the Client ID from the command line in GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-iap

I need to authenticate using IAP in Google Cloud Platform, but I am not able to get the Client ID of the proxy that protects the Airflow web server.

I need a command to do so as I can't use the `JSON` keys of a service account.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not through gcloud, but you could try something like: `curl --verbose https://url-for-your-app/ | grep Location: | sed 's/.*client_id=//' | sed 's/&.*//'`

Or through gcloud, I think `gcloud compute backend-services describe` will [show it](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/backend-services/describe).

Comment: Thanks @Matthew Sachs I tried a differnt version of the above command                           curl -s url-for-app | grep -Po 'client_id=[\D\S]*' | sed 's/.*client_id=//' | sed 's/&.*//' and it worked as a work around

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this is currently not possible to do using the `gcloud` CLI. There's a Feature Request for it [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/35907249), in which you may show your interest by clicking on the star button next to the Issue ID. Other than that, the only way to generate the OAuth Client ID is through the [Credentials](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials) page as per the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/authentication-howto#authenticating_from_a_desktop_app).

Comment: Thanks,but I cant access the Credentials page as suggested by you

Comment: @manishdev - You will need to look up the Client ID. This is not a secret that needs protection. Why are you not able to look this up in the credentials page? That is your only option.

Comment: @JohnHanley . I am able to see the client id at Credentials Page, but I need to automate the retrieval of client Id to trigger DAGs with client id through code

Comment: @manishdev I am not aware of an API to do this. Google does not publish APIs to manage OAuth or list OAuth objects beyond what the specification calls for.

Comment: @JohnHanley You are correct that there are no APIs to get client ID , hence had to find a work around to isolate the client id from Credentials

Comment: @manishdev - don't forget you can have more than one Client ID in a Google Cloud project. Be cautious with bandaid solutions. They break easily.

Comment: Thanks @JohnHanley ,this work aroud is to work for specific application in the GCP and for the time being only 1 client id is required and retrieved  but you are right that multiple clien ids can be there in GCP and for that I have raised an issue with GCP support to come up with APIs for this specific purpose

Comment: @manishdev I confident Google will not release a public API to obtain Client IDs in the near future. Google has not provided any APIs to manage OAuth Clients.