# Programmatically list Oauth 2.0 Client IDs in Google Cloud Platform project

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-iam, google-cloud-iam

There are many OAuth 2.0 Client IDs in my GCP project, and I would like to programmatically list them, along with their attributes (name, creation date, type, client ID).

However, the only API method I have been able to find is the one for [listing service accounts](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.serviceAccounts/list).

Is there an equivalent to list OAuth 2.0 Client IDs?

Please don't tell me to check them one by one by hand in the cloud [console](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials) :)

Thanks!

Comment: Looks like what you asking [does not exist yet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59678090/get-the-client-id-from-the-command-line-in-gcp)

Comment: I suspected as much :(